# Merge 2 arrays after 1 was in a loop

Tags: php

I have a form with a drop down. It looks at previous weeks results for an array of teams used. If the team was used it disables the selection on the drop down:
This is the working code:

```
echo '<select name="survpick" id="survpick">';
$thisweek = (int)getCurrentWeek()-1;

for ($pi=1; $pi<$week; $pi++) {
    if ($surv_pick_options_h[$j] == $survpicks[$pi]) {
        $noshowhome = true;
    }
    if ($surv_pick_options_v[$j] == $survpicks[$pi]) {
        $noshowvisitor = true;
    }
}

if ($noshowhome) {
    echo '<option value="" style="background-color:pink" disabled>'.$surv_pick_options_h[$j].'</option>';
} else {
    if ($currentID == $surv_pick_options_h[$j]) {
        echo '<option value="'.$surv_pick_options_h[$j].'"  selected>'.$surv_pick_options_h[$j].'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$surv_pick_options_h[$j].'" >'.$surv_pick_options_h[$j].'</option>';
    }
}

if ($noshowvisitor) {
    echo '<option value="" style="background-color:pink" disabled> '.$surv_pick_options_v[$j].'</option>';
}
else {
    if ($currentID == $surv_pick_options_v[$j]) {
        echo '<option value="'.$surv_pick_options_v[$j].'" selected>'.$surv_pick_options_v[$j].'</option>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<option value="'.$surv_pick_options_v[$j].'" >'.$surv_pick_options_v[$j].'</option>';
    }
}

echo '</select>';
```

I have 2 more arrays, one for current week home teams that have expired and one for current week visitor teams that expired. Somehow I need to account for those current week expired teams in the calculation. Since the for loop is only looking at previous weeks, i could not find a way to merge. I tried inside the loop and outside the loop. Is this even possible?

```
Array ( $survpicks)
[1] => DET 
[2] => TB 
[3] => NE 
[5] => JAX 
[4] => PHI 
[6] => IND 

Array ( $surv_pick_expired_h)
[0] => KC 

Array ($surv_pick_expired_v)
[0] => OAK
```

There is also a chance that one of the $survpicks could also be in one of the $surv_pick_expired_h or $surv_pick_expired_v arrays. Right now the drop down shows the values from $survpicks as disabled. I need to be able to also include the values from $surv_pick_expired_h and $surv_pick_expired_v arrays as disabled

Comment: Add input and desired output lists so we can see what you are trying to do with precision.  Thanks.

Comment: I fixed your indentation to make your code readable, please read [PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Comment: You would benefit a lot from reading about the [foreach](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct.

Comment: Also, what are the values of these variables: `$i, $week, $thisweek, $surv_pick_options_h, $surv_pick_options_v, $survpicks, $currentID`?

Comment: Just to see if I got it.  You want to have a select with values from $survpicks enabled, and values from $surv_pick_expired_h and $surv_pick_expired_v disabled?  Sorry I must be slow this morning, i do not understand your objective...

Comment: My apologies as I am fairly new to PHP coding. Basically, I  just want to know if it is possible to also disable the values from the $surv_pick_expired_h and $surv_pick_expired_v arrays, like it is already being done in the dropdown for the teams in $survpicks inside the for loop.

Comment: $i is a counter, $week is current week number, $thisweek is current week number -1, $surv_pick_options_h is all home teams in schedule for current week, $surv_pick_options_v is all visitor teams in schedule for current week, $survpicks is all previous selections from drop down for previous weeks, $currentID is current user logged in ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I hope this helps somewhat:

```
// this will contain all the survpicks up to last week,
// so now this week is not disabled
$survpicks_to_disable = array_slice($survpicks,0,$week-1);

// all the expired teams are to be disabled
$disabled = array_merge($survpicks_to_disable,$surv_pick_expired_h,$surv_pick_expired_v);

echo '<select name="survpick" id="survpick">
<option default>Make Selection</option>';

foreach($surv_pick_options_h as $home){
  echo '<option value="'.$home.'"'.(in_array($home,$disabled)?' style="background-color:pink" disabled':'').($home == $currentID?' selected':'').'>'.$home.'</option>';
}
foreach($surv_pick_options_v as $visitor){
  echo '<option value="'.$visitor.'"'.(in_array($visitor,$disabled)?' style="background-color:pink" disabled':'').($visitor == $currentID?' selected':'').'>'.$visitor.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Why not put this into your style, so you don't need the inline styles:

```
#survpick option[disabled] {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think this is extremely close. The only issue I am seeing is that it is taking into account the current week drop down selection, which it cannot unless the team is expired, which it would then fall into the expired array and be disabled.

Comment: I also had to change $currentID? to $surv_pick_options_v? and $surv_pick_options_h? respectively....  at least I understood what was done and knew how to fix it :)

Comment: so, 3 things  - it is including the current week $survpick, which it shouldn't, it does not default to the current week pick if it was made, and is there a way to highlight those disabled teams?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the current week selection piece.... Now down to "if current week selection already made, show as default value in dropdown" and highlighting the disabled picks with a color

Comment: changed it so the `$survpicks` are only disabled up to last week and added the background colour option back.

Comment: Ok, Highlight issue resolved - One final item is how to default to the users current selection if they made one? Not really sure on this one....

Comment: if the current selection is `$currentID` and it is not disabled it will put `selected` in the option. Do you want it to be selected even if it's disabled?

Comment: $currentID is actually the logged in users ID. I had to change those to $surv_pick_options_h? for home and $surv_pick_options_v? for visitor. Regardless if the team is disabled or not, if the user has already made a pick, then it should default to it. Icing on the cake would by, if the user made a pick, default to it, otherwise just show some text like "Make Pick" - I am asking a lot, but I think I am over my head on this, but a great learning experience.

Comment: My bad, $currentID would be the current pick.

Comment: Nevermind, not sure why I cahnged currentID, but I changed it back and it works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a way to default to "Make Pick" if the user has not made a selection for the week?

Comment: You can add a default option, that says 'make selection'.

Comment: Sorry for being so needy, but where/how would I add that?

Comment: `<option default>Make Selection</option>`

Comment: Programming can be awesome, but one part of it learning where to look for stuff. You already found stackoverflow, but there are some great resources, like the [PHP documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/), where you can search for built-in functions to suit your needs, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp), that has some good info on HTML and CSS, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), where you can quickly try out html, css and javascript and the [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) for javascript, html, css reference.

Comment: The trick is not knowing everything by heart, but knowing where to find the building blocks you need and putting them in the right order. Also, there is no perfect code. If you write something today, it is awesome, but if you come back to it a few months later, you will see some parts that can be made better with stuff you've learnt since then. This is true for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question, but may the [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php) and [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) functions help?

```
$toDisable = array_merge($survpicks, $surv_pick_expired_h,  $surv_pick_expired_v);

foreach($all as $something) {
  if(in_array($something, $toDisable)) {
    // disable
  } else {
    // enable
  }
}
```